# C++ casting template parameter to its unsigned version

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I'm working on a class template that takes a single parameter `T` of any type. For now I'm interested in `integral types`; later on when I expand this class to use `floating point types` I will then specialize this class.

Within this class I have a member variable that will store the max number of bit representations that can be stored in this type. For example:

**Fundamental Types & Sizes:** *Range of values*

- **`signed char:`** `1Byte`,`8 bits`,`[-127,127]` for one's complement or `[128,127]` for two's complement
- **`unsigned char:`** `1Byte`, `8 bits`, `[0,255]`
- etc.

I can get the max value easier by using the `unsigned version` of that type so in my template class (pseudo code here):

```
template<class T>
binaryRep {
    T t_; // store the value
    std::size_t size_ = sizeof( T ); // size in bytes
    std::size_t maxVal = T( -1 ); // This is where I need T to be it's unsigned version.    
};
```

If someone is to use this template class as such:

```
void someFunc() {
    binaryRep<unsigned char> binUC; // This works fine

    binaryRep<char> binSC; // Not giving the needed results.
}
```

Is there a way within the class's constructor to cast `T` to `unsigned T`?

In my constructor I was trying to do something like this:

```
binaryRep( const T& t ) : t_( static_cast<unsigned T>( t ) ) {
}
```

However this doesn't compile and didn't think it would either... but something of this nature is what I'm needing here.

[**Note:**] - The `maxValue` member in this class represents the total number of viable binary bit combinations this type can store. For example: both `char` & `unsigned char` of a standard `8 bit` `byte` has a max number of `256` binary bit combinations.

If you need more information than this please let me know.

Comment: I think you are looking for `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon not familiar with that part of the library... I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon well I'm trying to write a class template that will take a fundamental type and pass into it any value that that type normally accepts as a valid argument then it will process the information on that type and using ostream operator will display the value, size in bytes / bits, the max storage value representation and the binary bit pattern of that value with respect to that type.

Comment: While this is probably an XY-problem to some degree at least, [`std::make_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) should help with the task you stated.

Comment: Do you want the max or the number of distinct values? What do you need them for?

Comment: You can use template specialization : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin number of distinct values for example a `char` & `unsigned char` that has a standard `8-bit` `1 byte` size would have 256 total possible binary combinations.

Comment: @BartekPL I'll eventually be doing specialization when I separate this between `integral` & `floating` types.

Comment: I was finally able to get Baum mit Augen's recommendation to work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no `STL` in **C++** to give you an `unsigned datatype` of the `signed` version.

However, it isn't hard to write your own to get the `unsigned` type of the corresponding `signed` data type.

here is a sample of code I created for you.

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_signed { };

template<>
struct remove_signed<char> { typedef unsigned char Type; };

template<>
struct remove_signed<signed char> { typedef unsigned char Type; };

template<>
struct remove_signed<signed short int> { typedef unsigned short int Type; };

template<>
struct remove_signed<signed int> { typedef unsigned int Type; };

template<>
struct remove_signed<signed long int> { typedef unsigned long int Type; };

template<>
struct remove_signed<signed long long> { typedef unsigned long long Type; };


template<typename T>
using remove_signed_t = typename remove_signed<T>::Type;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   
    signed int x;
    remove_signed<decltype(x)>::Type y; //y is unsigned int

    signed char k;
    remove_signed<decltype(k)>::Type l; //l is unsigned char

    //or
    remove_signed_t<decltype(k)> g; //g is unsigned char
    
    return 0;
}
```

Good luck.

Edit: As @HolyBlackCat has mentioned, there is `std::make_unsigned` which can give you `unsigned` datatype of the `signed` type
And it is exactly implemented as the code above, so if you want to know how `std::make_unsigned` works, you can check the code.

Comment: `std::make_unsigned`? Also you neef to specialize for `char`, which is distinct from `signed char`.

Comment: it is my first time to know about `std::make_unsigned`
and I haven't typed all possible datatypes, that's why I said "a sample of code".

I just gave him the basic idea, which is similar to `std::remove_cv`

Comment: I think you added all the necessary types, except one, which is the least obvious of them  all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right I will add it to the code so it looks complete for the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `maxVal` to `size_ == sizeof(long long) ? (uLL) -1 : (1uLL << size_) - 1` should do the trick.

Comment: It's possible I could use that, but I'm trying to make this as generic and automated as possible. However, will `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` return the max value it can hold, or the total number of binary combinations?

Comment: std::numeric_limits<T>::max() will return max value T can hold. For signed types it will return less than 2^sizeof(T) - 1.

Comment: `1 << size_` causes UB when `int` is 32-bit and `size_ >= 32`.

Comment: @haaawk Yeah I don't need the max value that the variable can hold per say; I need the max value of the unsigned version of that type. `unsigned char(-1)` returns `255` which is needed as opposed to `char(-1)`. Same thing for `unsigned short(-1)` returns 65535 as opposed to `short(-1)`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler then setting `maxVal` to `size_ == sizeof(long long) ? (uLL) -1 : (1uLL << size_) - 1` would do the trick. I don't know how you're planning to make this template work with float and double but for integral types this will work.

Comment: @haaawk eventually I'll specialize this template for floating types and do the algorithm completely different.